# Canvas and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Is it possible to use jQuery with the HTML5 `<canvas>` element?  Or do I have to do it with plain JavaScript?

I'm just wondering, because I think I could save a lot of time with using jQuery, but I have no clue about the `<canvas>` element's uses yet, so it may be completely impossible!

Anyone know if I *can* use jQuery for this?

Comment: You may find this plugin useful: http://iwhitcomb.github.io/dynamocanvas/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use jQuery to `select` the canvas element, but you'd have to use its own methods. A decent start would be https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial.

Comment: OK, that would actually save a lot of time really, instead of all that getElementbyID or whatever it is.  So, if the jQuery library is "extended" or whatever you call the term, would it be possible to leverage jQuery with `<canvas>` in the future?  Fully, I mean.

Comment: *Why* can't you just use canvas's own methods?

Comment: I didn't say I couldn't, I'm guessing those are separate from JavaScript completely?

Comment: jQuery is a library to interact with the DOM. It isn't targeted to abstract canvas's methods.

Comment: But, there's nothing wrong with doing what you said now is there?  Using it to select, and using JavaScript and canvas' methods for the actual manipulation.

Comment: That would be like buying $200 worth of tools and using just a screwdriver from that set. Sure there's nothing wrong, but if your entire goal is to do mostly canvas-scripting you don't need jQuery at all.

Comment: Good point! :) You've been referencing Canvas' own methods, and are there a specific set of methods from the `<canvas>` API that are separate from JavaScript?  And then libraries like Raphael make it easier to use in a way?

Comment: canvas is defined in HTML 5. http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html

Comment: Raphael is different from canvas. Raphael is for SVG/Vector graphics. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/568136/svg-vs-canvas-where-is-the-web-world-going-towards

Comment: You can also use exCanvas for IE implementations.

Comment: Phew, ok, kind of confusing, but I think I got it! :) But, just wondering, are `<canvas>`'s APIs only defined through JavaScript?

Answer (score 14):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is a toolkit to interact and manipulate the DOM plus some extra neat ajax methods. 
[Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) and/or [Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/) are toolkits for visualisation.

[Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/) is a visualisation toolkit specifically for the canvas element.

jQuery has one expertise, other toolkits have other expertise, though it's very much possible to use specialisation toolkits together ;)

Answer (score 6):

The direct answer is no because jQuery is based on DOM querying and manipulation.  Canvas elements are drawn using the Canvas API with JavaScript.  If you're looking for a good canvas library, you might try out [KineticJS](http://www.kineticjs.com).  It adds animation and event support for canvas applications.

Answer (score 5):

## [jCanvas](http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/)

Besides using jQuery to select the canvas and then using the built-in canvas methods, you can also check out [jCanvas](http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/), which is a "nice" wrapper around the canvas API that you might find easier/better/clearer. I know I did.

This is what it looks like:

```
// Draw a circle
$("canvas").drawArc({
  draggable: true,
  fillStyle: "green",
  x:         100, 
  y:         100,
  radius:    50
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/). This is yet the best project I've seen so far using something similar to canvas (thus supported in all major browsers) and Javascript (JQuery).

Comment: yes it does. It also uses VML with Internet Explorer (I'm on Linux, so I don't know nor care much what implementation IE now support... Raphaël works with IE 6+ and this is good enough to me). I corrected my answer because it is effectively misleading. :)

Answer (score 0):

the answer would be yes.  you need to use the plain JavaScript..

how ever there is a jQuery plug-in that came in handy for me:
 http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/

it gives you access to the canvas using the jQuery formatting that we are used for .

Answer (score -1):

```
var canvas=($('<canvas width="200" height="1"></canvas>'))[0];
```

Comment: Currently, this answer is listed as a low quality post. We don't really encourage a code-only answer as it may confuse other people. It would be better if you can improve this answer, maybe by explaining it a little bit.